# Cookies occured in request hearder

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I have created the cookie less sub domain for static content. All static content are comming via cookie less domain. But I review all request in firebug and see cookies are available with request header. How to remove cookie form request header.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent by each client at their discretion. You can only control the cookies you send back in the response, not what the client sends in the request. However, you're free to ignore any cookies you receive.

That said, under most circumstances you will only receive cookies that were sent from your server via a [set-cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#innerlink_set-cookie) header in your response. So perhaps your clients are caching cookies that were previously sent from your domain.

Comment: In amazon and yahoo website used static domain and there are no any cookie available in request header.

Comment: You should post the output of Firebug or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) so I can better understand your question.